# Display List return from a controller to a table in view ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

I have a function in my controller class, it return a list of data, I want to display it in table structure in my view page.
i have tried the following code but it shows some error

> "Class does not contain definition of GetEnumerator"

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult data(Message msg,IEnumerable<sample> dept)
{
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    sample s = new sample();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
    DataTable dt;   
    List<examplemvc1.Models.sample> datatable = new List<sample>();
    dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
        s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
        s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
        s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
        s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
        datatable.Add(s);
        dept = datatable;  
    }
    ViewBag.tabledata = dept;
    return View(dept) ;
}
```

**Model**

```
public class sample
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string tabledata { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public IEnumerable<sample> sampleList { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model examplemvc1.Models.sample

@foreach (var data in Model)
{
    <table><tr><td>@data.FirstName</td></tr></table>
}
```

**UPDATE**
this is how my entire view looks like

```
@model List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration Form";
}
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Style/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/samplescript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<h2>
    Registration Form </h2>
   <body>

  <table>
 <tr>
 <th>
   First Name
 </th>
 </tr>

@foreach (var data in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@data.FirstName</td></tr>
}
</table>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table id="table1">
    <tr>
         <td> 

             @Html.Label("Enter FirstName", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
        </td>
         <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.FirstName, new { @class = "class1", title = "Enter FirstName", id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Enter name", onkeydown = "return TextField(event)" })
          <span class="errorMessage"></span>
           @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
           {       
                <span class="field-validation-error">
                @ViewData.ModelState["FirstName"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage</span>
           }     
    </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>
    @Html.Label("Enter LastName", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
    </td>
    <td>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LastName, new { @class = "class1", placeholder = "Enter name", id = "LastNameBox", title = "Enter Lastname", onkeydown = "return TextField(event); " })
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
     @Html.Label("Enter Address", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
     </td>
     <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Address, new { @class = "class1", id = "AddressBox", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Enter Address" })
    <span class="errorMessage"></span>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>
    @Html.Label("Enter PhoneNumber", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "class1", id = "PhoneBox", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Enter Phonenumber", onkeydown = "return ValidateNumber(event);" })
    <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    @Html.Label("Enter Location", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
    </td><td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Location, new { @class = "class1", id = "LocationBox", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Enter Location" })
      <span class="errorMessage"></span>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
    <input type="button" id="btnSave"  value="Register"/>
     <input type="button" value="Clear"/>
     <input type="button" id="Tabledata" value="Tabledata"/>
    <div id="div1"></div>

   @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@








   <script type="text/javascript">

       function ValidateNumber(e) {
           var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
           var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
           if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       };
       function TextField(e) {
           var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
           var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
           if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 56)) {
               return true;
           }
           else if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 9) {
               return true;
           }
           return false

       };


   </script>

}
   </body>
```

Error is shown in my view code, actually I don't know how to get that values in view page. I am newbie in mvc. Please help me to solve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**"Update"**

**I have solved My problem with the help of Stackoverflow Below is my correctcode**

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult data()
        {
            SomeViewModel model = new SomeViewModel();
            dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
            DataTable dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sample s = new sample();
                s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
                s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
                s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
                s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
                s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
                model.samples.Add(s);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Model**

```
namespace examplemvc1.Models
{
    public class sample
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }


        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }
         public string tabledata { get; set; }

    }
    public class Message
    {
        public IEnumerable<sample> sampleList { get; set; }
        public string MessageText { get; set; }
        public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
    }
    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public SomeViewModel()
        {
            samples = new List<sample>();
            sample = new sample();
        }
        public List<sample> samples { get; set; }
        public sample sample { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**view**

```
@model examplemvc1.Models.SomeViewModel
```

//................

```
@foreach (var data in Model.samples)
{
    <tr><td>@data.FirstName</td>
     <td>@data.LastName</td>
     <td>@data.Address</td>
     <td>@data.PhoneNumber</td>
     <td>@data.Location</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

**Just look at Stephen Muecke's Answer below he has explained the context very clearly**

Comment: Have you specified model directive on the start of page like `model List<namespace.sample>`?

Comment: Show how you have declared the model in the view. But you have multiple other errors in your code (for example every row will have identical values)

Comment: @JenishRabadiya ,yes like  model examplemvc1.Models.sample like thi

Comment: It is wrong make it list<model> or IEnumerable<Model>.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya ok i will try

Comment: Based on your edit, you need a view model with a property for the 'new' `sample` and a property for the existing collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i make that ?

Comment: Create a view model, say `class SampleVM` and add `public List<sample> SampleCollection { get; set; } public sample NewSample { get; set; }` and pass that to the view, but you have multiple other errors in your code. I'll add a detailed answer later.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your replay, please give me an updated answer when you are free, i can wait until that, also i can have a try too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You view is displaying both a list of `sample` and what appears t be a form for a new `sample`. Start by creating a view model to represent what you want to display/edit

```
public class SampleVM
{
  public SampleVM
  {
      SampleCollection = new List<sample>
  }
  public List<sample> SampleCollection { get; set; }
  public sample NewSample { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller modify the code to

```
public ActionResult data()
{
    SampleVM model = new SampleVM();
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
    DataTable dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        sample s = new sample();
        s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
        s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
        s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
        s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
        s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
        model.SampleCollection.Add(s);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Notes:

1. Remove the parameters from the GET method. Apart from the fact you
   don't use them so they are pointless, even if you were to try and
   pass those objects to the method, binding would fail and the
   collections would be null (and if you were to construct the correct
   query string to make it work, it would be so long it would almost
   certainly throw an exception)
2. You need to initialize a new `sample` inside the `foreach` loop
   (your code only initialized one object, and each loop updated its
   properties to the current row, so you would end up with multiple
   reference of the same object, all matching the values of the last
   row in your table)
3. There is no need to pass the model as a `ViewBag` property (its
   already passed to the view using `return View(model);`

And modify your view to

```
@model SampleVM
....
<table>
    @foreach(var sample in Model.SampleCollection)
        <tr>
            <td>@sample .FirstName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
@Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewSample.FirstName, "Enter FirstName", new { @class = "standard_label_style" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewSample.FirstName, @class = "class1", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Enter Lastname")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewSample.FirstName)
}
....
<input type="submit" id="btnSave"  value="Register"/>
```

Notes:

1. A label element if for associating the element with a control. Your
   usage generates `<label for="Enter_FirstName">` but you dont have a
   control with `id="Enter_FirstName"`. Preferable you should have
   `[Display(Name = "Enter FirstName")]` on the property, but otherwise
   use the strongly types helper
2. Use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to render `ModelState` errors,
   although in your case all you properties are strings and you don't
   have any validation attributes so there will never be any errors, so
   its a bit pointless
3. The html helpers generate an `id` attribute. There is rarely a need
   to overwrite it. Stop polluting your markup with behavior and learn
   to use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)
4. Your form did not contain a submit button

Comment: I see you couldn't wait!

Comment: Thanks for helping me, already i had solved my problem, +1 for detailed explanation

Comment: Actually, no you haven't, and had you taken the time to test the accepted answer you would know that it did not work.

Comment: may be it has errors,  i did not take the accepted answer , The thing isi had chat with him and there i had solved my problem, he is helping to solve my problm in stackoverflow chat, that's why i had ticked it as accepted answer

Comment: I don't care if you accept my answer or not, but the fact is you accepted an answer (which incidentally was edited each time I made a comment) that does not work and  will be confusing to others who come across this.

Comment: Yes i  agree your thought, already i had updated my working code with my question , also i  request Jenish to edit his answer to correct , otherewise it will misleading someone, you are right

Comment: If nothing else, please read all the notes in my answer carefully. Your edited question still contains multiple errors in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your valid  suggestions . i will note it

Comment: You are pointing every mistakes, good clarification about the problems, nice suggestions ...so your answer needs accepted by the questioner. Thanks for your valid informations

Comment: @StephenMuecke your explanation is great you deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your model is of Type `examplemvc1.Models.sample` while you have to pass object of `List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>` to view:

```
 return View(datatable) ;
```

Your action:

```
List <examplemvc1.Models.sample> datatable = new List<sample>();

dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
       s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
       s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
       s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
       s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
       datatable.Add(s);
    }


    return View(datatable);  // passing list to view
```

and in View set model to `List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>`:

```
@model List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>
```

and now iterate the way you are doing:

```
<table>
 <thead>
 <tr><th>First Name</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
@foreach (var data in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@data.FirstName</td></tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i had change the code but it throws an error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you sure you are doing the way i posted?

Comment: Yes i had done that , change the model declaration in the way you are shown

Comment: yes sure , the problem is i have used some textbox fields in my code and that data to be saved in model parameters so when i change model examplemvc1.Models.sample to model List<examplemvc1.Models.sample> it throws error

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV `foreach` is fine issue is down in form, you cannot do it like that

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV you need to create a **ViewModel** class

Comment: I had create that and now try to solve my issue, +1 for your valid suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is with your model directive.

It should be

```
@model IEnumerable<examplemvc1.Models.sample>
```

instead of

```
@model examplemvc1.Models.sample
```

**Note**: You are making assignment few times like `dept = datatable;` instead you can update the code like this.

```
public ActionResult data(Message msg,IEnumerable<sample> dept)
    {

        dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
        sample s = new sample();
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
        DataTable dt;

            List <examplemvc1.Models.sample> datatable = new List<sample>();

           dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
               s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
               s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
               s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
               s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
               s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
               datatable.Add(s);

              //dept = datatable;

           }
            ViewBag.tabledata = datatable;

            return View(datatable) ;
    }
```

**Update**
In such a case you need to create viewmodel first and pass his instance there as model.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        samples = new List<sample>();
        sample = new sample();
    }
    public List<sample> samples {get; set;}
    public sample sample {get; set;}
}
```

and in model declaration

```
@model namespace.SomeViewModel
```

and then in controller like following.

```
public ActionResult data(Message msg,IEnumerable<sample> dept)
{
    dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
    sample s = new sample();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.GetconString());
    DataTable dt;   
    List<examplemvc1.Models.sample> datatable = new List<sample>();
    dt = db.BuildDT("select * from MVCsample");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        s.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["First Name"]);
        s.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["Last Name"]);
        s.Address = Convert.ToString(row["Address"]);
        s.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(row["PhoneNumber"]);
        s.Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]);
        datatable.Add(s);
        dept = datatable;  
    }
    ViewBag.tabledata = dept;
    SomeViewModel vm = new SomeViewModel();
    vm.samples = datatable;
    vm.sample = //somesample instance here you want to edit.

    return View(vm) ;
}
```

and in view you will get the instance of vm iterate through vm.samples

```
@foreach (var data in Model.samples)
{
    <tr><td>@data.FirstName</td></tr>
}
```

and in the rest of view do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.sample.FirstName, new { @class = "class1", title = 
"Enter FirstName", id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Enter name", onkeydown = 
"return TextField(event)" })
```

Comment: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<examplemvc1.Models.sample>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i had made the change and the old error disapperes and now it shows the old error foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'examplemvc1.Models.sample' because 'examplemvc1.Models.sample' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV you may Check it now.

Comment: @foreach (var data in Model.samples) it shows error ,  actually what is Models.samples ? i didn't get that

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Its a list containing few sample object. What is the error? have you updated model directive in view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71075/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-jenish-rabadiya).